How to get documents inside subcollections of documents inside an outer collection using Firebase Firestore Queries
I want to get documents inside a collection within documents in an outer collectio. For instance I have a collection of soda brands which has two documents, coke and fanta, and each of these has a collection with flavours inside, for the coke, the flavours collection has documents for diet and original flavours
The fanta brand also has a collecton of flavours with documents for grape and orange flavours.
I want to be able to bring back all four flavours diet, original, grape and orange, from the two brands coke and fanta.
I tried using a wildcard "*" in my firestore query but it doesn't work.

Is it better? or do you have an alternate suggestion?

You're looking for a collection group query, which returns documents from all collections with a specific name.
If that doesn't allow you to implement the use-case, you'll need to change the data model to fit the use-case.
If you tried collection group queries, but can't get them to work, edit your question to show what you tried.
If you hadn't heard of collection group queries yet, read the docs, try to get them to work - and post a new question with a minimal repro if you get stuck.
